# Group results after count in customized groups

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I recently started using MongoDB and I am trying to count `cities` by the `region` field and then group the results.

This is what each object (`city`) has.

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"6004c22c8ae7492c58ccf158"},"name":"Seoul","country":"South Korea","countryCode":"kr","region":"as"}
```

`region`, will always be one of these: `eu, as, na, sa, af, oc`.
But it might happen that no object has one of the regions, so maybe there is no object with region "eu" but I still need to get an answer even if its 0.

The result I would like to get would be something like this:

```
{"eu":10,"as":5,"na":2,"sa":2,"af":0,"oc":1}
```

I've been trying to modify different code I found all over the internet but I am unable to make it work.

Thank you in advance. It's my first time asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- set all `regions` to zero in a variable
- `$group` by region and get unique array of `cities` using `$addToSet`
- `$group` by null and make array of object k and v format, get size of cities array using `$size`
- `$arrayToObject` convert array to object
- `$mergeObjects` to merge our `regions` object and converted object from above operator

```
let regions = { "eu": 0, "as": 0, "na": 0, "sa": 0, "af": 0, "oc": 0 };

db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$region",
      cities: { $addToSet: "$name" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      docs: { $push: { k: "$_id", v: { $size: "$sizes" } } }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      docs: {
        $mergeObjects: [regions, { $arrayToObject: "$docs" }]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Txujp15FItN)